# Windows. Change drop-down menu position

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to change the position of the popup menu. With top-level windows I can do it by CBTProc Callback Function and MoveWindow. Can I do the same with menus? Needs to be done so that the pop-up menu is located only in the area of its parent window. Something like a light window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a `WH_CBT` hook callback, you'll be notified with an 'nCode' of `HCBT_CREATEWND` whenever a menu window is created. Test for the class name, standard menu/submenu windows would have a class name of '#32768'. You can then send a [`MN_GETHMENU`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632613%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the window to find out which menu is about to be activated. But [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is too early to move the window when the notification is received, the menu is not even visible yet, so you might need to sub-class the window and process additional messages.

Note that you don't need a hook to be notified when a menu window is shown, you can put a handler for the [`WM_ENTERIDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, test for 'wParam' to see if a menu caused the message, get the menu window from 'lParam' and again send a 'MN_GETHMENU' to find out the specific menu. It is possible to move the window at this point without further message handling. Just be aware that 'WM_ENTERIDLE' will be called multiple times so you need to keep track of you've already moved a particular window or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's what I need! Now I try to do the same with the context menu, but can not find a suitable window message to catch it. Can you advise me something?

Comment: @Alexander - Tested with a Delphi application, both methods seem to work. Be sure to pass your window's handle to `TrackPopupMenu[ex]` for the `hwnd` parameter as it denotes the window which will receive messages.