# Align a TPopupMenu to the right hand side of the form?

Tags: delphi, winapi

How can a TPopupMenu be aligned to the right hand side of a form? The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to get the width of the Popup menu before you call `Popup(X, Y: Integer)`.

I'm trying to get a behavior similar to that of the system menu in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: [Windows. Change drop-down menu position](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4721989)

Comment: @Sertac - I don't see how this is a duplicate question. a) It's tagged with Delphi. b) It's not about simply moving the popup. It requires that the width of the menu be known so the position can be calculated.

Comment: Before you move the menu window, you can get its size/position. The VCL does not offer the functionality you ask, hence you have to use api calls. I think that makes it a duplicate, but maybe not..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could also just set [`Alignment`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu.Alignment) to `paRight` and call

```
with ClientToScreen(Point(ClientWidth - 1, 0)) do
  Popup(X, Y);
```

Comment: +1 for pure VCL solution (as in "_knowing the Win API is good, but knowing how not to use it is better_")

Comment: There's an odd buglet with this solution. If you have dual monitors and the application is maximised, the popup will appear on the second monitor. The simple fix is to use ClientWidth - 1.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest solution would be to launch the popup menu yourself:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  PopupPt: TPoint;
begin
  PopupPt := ClientToScreen(Point(ClientWidth, 0));
  TrackPopupMenu(PopupMenu1.Handle, TPM_RIGHTALIGN or TPM_TOPALIGN,
      PopupPt.X, PopupPt.Y, 0, PopupList.Window, nil);
end;
```

See documentation for [`TrackPopupMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`TrackPopupMenuEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for what various flags mean.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I'd been trying to figure out how to force a popup menu to expand upward. I knew there had to be a way but this was the closest topic I found. TrackPopupMenu wtih TPM_BOTTOMALIGN was exactly what I needed. I'm saying all this in case someone else is searching for something similar.