# Delphi Calculate TPopupMenu size

Tags: delphi, popup, size, calculation

I have button that shows popup menu on click. Have two options show it below or on right side.

If screen is big enough it is easy just do

For below:

```
Pt := Self.ClientToScreen(self.ClientRect.TopLeft);
pt.Y := pt.Y + Self.Height;
PopupMenu.Popup( pt.X, pt.Y);
```

For right:

```
Pt := Self.ClientToScreen(self.ClientRect.TopLeft);
Pt.X := PT.X + Self.Width;
PopupMenu.Popup( pt.X, pt.Y);
```

But problem is when there is not enough space on screen for that. In that case popup menu is automatically positioned but it comes above button. I do not want that. In case there is no space below I want to make it above. But for that I need height and width.

Calculation of height:

```pascal
 Function getPopUpHeight: Integer;
  var i: Integer;
      tmpHeight: Integer;
  begin
    result := 0;
    tmpHeight := 0;
    Self.Canvas.Font := Screen.MenuFont;
    for i := PopupMenu.items.count - 1 downto 0 do begin
    //do for all items
    if PopupMenu.Items[i].Visible then begin //process visible
        if (PopupMenu.Items[i].IsLine OR (PopupMenu.Items[i].Caption = '-')) then begin
          //if seperator line
          tmpHeight:= 6;
          result := result + tmpHeight;
        end else begin
          //if actual item
          result := result + Self.Canvas.TextHeight(PopupMenu.Items[i].Caption) + 6 ;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Calculation for width

```pascal
  Function GetPopupWidth: Integer;
  var i, lStLine:integer;
  begin
    result := 0;
    lStLine := 0;
    self.Canvas.Font.Size := Screen.MenuFont.Size;
    for i:=0 to PopupMenu.Items.Count-1 do begin
    if PopupMenu.Items[i].Visible then begin
      if (PopupMenu.Items[i].IsLine OR (PopupMenu.Items[i].Caption = '-')) then begin
        inc(lStLine);
      end else begin
        if result < (self.Canvas.TextWidth(PopupMenu.items[i].Caption) + 9) then begin
         result := Self.Canvas.TextWidth(PopupMenu.items[i].Caption) + 9;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    end;
    if lStLine > 0 then begin
    result := result + 58;
    end;
  end;
```

But there is something missing from my calculation because there is random behavior sometimes it is right sometimes not. Sometimes is to high and sometime is to low.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or forgetting?

Comment: This looks misplaced in `GetPopupWidth`: `if lStLine > 0 then result := result + 58;` Why would this have anything to do with the width?

Comment: This is done because width of text is not enough. Menu has some space on left and right. And I have tested and that number have me best result. But cant do same with height because I get some strange behavior which I don't know how to explain.

Comment: But why is the width wrong only if there is a horizontal line ( separator item ) in the menu?

Comment: Yes thet "IF" is wrong. But most problematic is getPopUpHeight

Comment: > *`Pt := Self.ClientToScreen(self.ClientRect.TopLeft);`" - From the docs: *ClientRect returns a rectangle with its Top and Left fields set to zero ... *.

Comment: You can use TrackPopupMenuEx instead of "Popup", where you can specify a non-overlappable rectangle.

Comment: One of the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860642/how-do-you-line-up-a-tpopupmenu-so-that-it-accurately-positions-itself-above-a-b) demonstrates a way to determine and modify the position of a menu's window. Manually calculating using magic constants won't go far.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes calculating right size is impossible. Like I wrote at beginning. I used above article by you to solve my problem. It now works as I want without this calculations. This article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873245/14097541 Thank you