# Is it possible to override the global Windows context menu placement in relation to the location where the click happened?

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, dllimport

I would like to override the location where a context menu shows up in Windows. By default, a context menu shows up with the top left corner exactly where the mouse was clicked (unless this would cause the context menu to popup outside the display). I would like to override this behavior globally so that I can choose some other popup location but I could not find the relevant Win32 API call(s)/WndProc message.

I had the idea of sending "incorrect" mouse coordinates on click so that I can get the desired context menu location but I think it would be too cumbersome and may cause other issues and so was hoping there was an easier and safer solution.

Edit: In case I was not clear enough, I want to override the location where all context menus in the OS show up.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4721989/1997232) helpful?

Comment: Not as simple as I thought it would be but I'll play around with it a little and see if it gets me anywhere, thanks.

Comment: TrackPopupMenuEx(), x and y arguments.  But surely pinvoking it is pointless since context menus are already wrapped in .NET and the wrappers certainly allow you to position the menu.  Nobody can guess what wrapper is the right one when you don't document what you use.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well enough. What I want to do is to override the location where Windows places context menus of all applications and system menus including Windows Explorer.

Comment: I don't think you can overwrite this behaviour globally (could be a security issue). Only within your own application.

Comment: Menus are just windows of a particular class; with the right hook you could probably intercept their creation and reposition them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at a combination of the answer linked in @Sinatr's comment and `TrackPopupMenuEx()`; I'm not sure it'll work yet but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Be sure to understand the usability implications. In a system that has enabled a left-handed mouse, a context menu opens towards the opposite direction. Likewise, when using a touch input system, the context menu location and direction are adjusted as well. A solution that is just as good as the system-provided implementation is a lot of work to get right.

Comment: Yes I understand, I'm working with a hardware input device that is not a mouse, but has a driver such that it is detected as a mouse and want to emulate context menus as they show up on touch-enabled devices.